# C# create an interface for a generic class with generic methods

Tags: c#, generics

Let say I have this piece of code

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

public abstract class FooBase<TModel> : IFoo
{
    public T Create<T>() where T : TModel;
}

public class Foo : FooBase<ModelBase>
{
    public TModel Create<TModel>()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TModel));
    }
}

public abstract class ModelBase
{
}

public class ModelFoo : ModelBase
{
}

public class ModelBar : ModelBase
{
}
```

Now, let say I have this class

```
public static FooProvider
{
    public IFoo Get<TModel>()
    {
        var provider = ...; // find which IFoo class has generic TModel
        return provider;
    }
}
```

And I can manage to call this with

```
IFoo provider = FooProvider.Get<ModelBar>();  // -> instance of Foo
```

But I get an instance of `IFoo`, therefore don't have access to the `FooBase` methods. Is it possible to implement `IFoo` (or an intermediary abstract class) to provide a method declaration that can be called without (necessarily) casting the return value `provider`?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do

```
ModelBar bar = FooProvider.Get<ModelBar>().Create<ModelBar>();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What about returning `FooBase<TModel>` instead of `IFoo`?

Comment: Because I need to return `FooBase<ModelBase>` when calling `Get<ModelBar>`. As you can see, `TModel` is `ModelBar`, not `ModelBase` and I cannot cast `Foo` into `FooBase<ModelBar>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question evolved, I'm posting second answer. Here's a sample class hierarchy which:

- allows to use same provider for many model types
- allows to construct many different providers and models in a consistent way
- checks provider/model compatibility at **compile time**
- does not need casting during usage

Code:

```
public interface IWhatever { }

public class Foo { }
public class Foo2 : Foo, IWhatever { }

public class Bar { }
public class Bar2 : Bar { }
public class Bar3 : Bar, IWhatever { }


public interface IModelProvider<T>
{
    U Create<U>() where U : T;
}

public class FooProvider : IModelProvider<Foo>
{
    public U Create<U>() where U : Foo
    {
        // create a proper "U" - for example Foo or Foo2
        return Activator.CreateInstance<U>(); // simpliest
    }
}

public class BarProvider : IModelProvider<Bar>
{
    public U Create<U>() where U : Bar
    {
        // create a proper "U" - for example Bar, Bar2 or Bar3
        // more verbose
        if (typeof(U) == typeof(Bar)) return (U)new Bar();
        if (typeof(U) == typeof(Bar2)) return (U)(object)new Bar2();
        if (typeof(U) == typeof(Bar3)) return (U)(object)new Bar3();

        throw new Exception();
    }
}

public class WhateverProvider : IModelProvider<IWhatever>
{
    public U Create<U>() where U : IWhatever, new()
    {
        // create a proper "U" - for example Foo2 or Bar3
        return new U(); // really the simpliest
    }
}
```

public class VeryGenericProvider : IModelProvider
    {
        public TModel Create() where TModel : new()
        {
            return new TModel();
        }
    }

```
public class ProviderFactory
{
    public static IModelProvider<T> Get<T>() where T : new()
    {
        // somehow choose a provider for T, dumb implementation just for example purposes
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Foo)) return (IModelProvider<T>)new FooProvider();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Bar)) return (IModelProvider<T>)new BarProvider();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(IWhatever)) return (IModelProvider<T>)new WhateverProvider();

        return VeryGenericProvider<T>();
    }
}

public static class ProviderTest
{
    public static void test()
    {
        Foo foo = ProviderFactory.Get<Foo>().Create<Foo>();
        Foo2 foo2 = ProviderFactory.Get<Foo>().Create<Foo2>();

        // Bar2 bar2 = ProviderFactory.Get<Foo>().Create<Bar2>(); - compile error
        Bar2 bar2 = ProviderFactory.Get<Bar>().Create<Bar2>(); // - ok!

        Bar3 bar3 = ProviderFactory.Get<IWhatever>().Create<Bar3>();
    }
}
```

This code compiles, but I have not run it. Note that the final usage in the "test" does perform type checks and does not need any casts -- but the provider's internal implementation surely will need to cast a few things - for example please see the BarProvider which manually constructs the objects. Even if "we know" for sure that U is Bar2, there is no way to tell the language to upgrade the constraint over U from Bar to Bar2 - hence a double cast is needed.

I mean this:

```
return (U)new Bar(); // is ok because U is constrained to 'Bar'
```

versus

```
return (U)new Bar2();         // will not compile, U:Bar is not related to Bar2:Bar
return (U)(object)new Bar2(); // is ok: temporary cast to object 'erases' type information
```

Comment: You can have a slightly stronger compile time check in your code to determine whether creating a new instance will succeed using the `new()` generic constraint: `U Create<U>() where U : T, new()` which will enable you to simply `return new U();` rather than `return Activator.CreateInstance<U>()`.

Comment: Yes indeed! I copied the object-creation code from the question, I assume it will be replaced with something more complicated, as Activator can accept construciton parameters and the `new()` constraint cannot (at least as of .Net4/.5). I didn't want to complicate the sample more than absolutely needed.

Comment: In fact, as I already wrote 3 different sample providers, I've upgraded `WhateverProvider` to use the `new()` constraint. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: So, this looks quite like my original implementation. All that tells me is that I cannot call `ProviderFactory.Get<Foo2>()`, which is what I was trying to do. Thansk you for your time!

Comment: You can do that. ProviderFactory.Get<Foo2>().Create<Foo2>() will compile - the only thing you must correct in the above example is to make the GET implementation recognize the Foo2 and return a proper provider for it (here, a `FooProvider` or `WhateverProvider` as both of them can construct Foo2. First on behalf of Foo inheritance, second on behalf of IWhatever implementation)

Comment: Sorry, error in last comment. The case of Get<Foo2> would need to return IModelProvider<Foo2>, which would force you to specify that FooProvider implements IModelProvider<Foo2>, IModelProvider<Foo4> and so on. You must make your mind. Either you GET by base class and CREATE by final class, or either you GET by final class and JUST-CREATE as I shown in the first answer. Those two options yield different factory/provider architecture. The third option you wanted, GET-by-final-type and CREATE-by-final-type is superfluous. Theres no need to repeat the Type if it always the same for Get and Create.

Comment: I was asking this question because `ProviderFactory.Get<Foo2>()` did not work, as generics `IModelProvider<T>` (`Foo2`) cannot be cast into `IModelProvider<Foo2>`, and can only be cast into `Foo`. Getting by base class works. I find it too bad that C# does not have generics wildcard like Java....

Comment: Instead of "wildcard" that erases the type information, in C# you have **variance** options, the `blah<in T>` and `blah<out T>` and usually they do very well if your class hierarchy and usage is well thought. However, I currently don't see how to benefit from them here.

Comment: If IModelProvider were defined as `IModelProvider<out T>`, then IModelProvider<Foo3> would be castable to IModelProvider<Foo> and to IModelProvider<object>, but not the other way around. To allow casts from IModelProvider<Foo> to IModelProvider<Foo3>, an `<in T>` would be needed, what is invalid for `T Get<T>()` method signature.

Comment: Such provider is doable, but it gets a bit hairy: `class FooProvider<TRealFoo> : IModelProvider<TRealFoo> {  TRealFoo Create() { .... }   }`. Now, in the factory: `if(typeof() == typeof(Foo2)) return new FooProvider<Foo2>();`. Note that now FooProv is typed by final type. Now it is castable to proper IModelProvider<Foo2> even if his implementation does not know about it. This is neat, but may interfere a bit with provider OBJECT reuse (provider class/code reuse is unaffected)

Comment: I've added a VeryGenericProvider to the above code. However, it is **really generic** in the literal sense ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

```
ModelBar bar = FooProvider.Get<ModelBar>().Create<ModelBar>();
```

or rather

```
ModelBar bar = FooProvider.Get<ModelBar>().Create();
```

?

I find the former a bit strange unless you have some cases where first ModelBar is actually ModelBarBase or IModelBar and the latter ModelBar is in fact the final constructable type.

Anyways, I also find your class layout a little strange, as in your code example the Get() and Create() come from the same class (Foo/FooBase). I think you messed up with SRP here.

I'd recommend:

```
public class FooProvider
{
    public static Provider<T> Get<T> { return new Provider<T>(); };
}

public class Provider<T>
{
    public T CreateDirect()
    {
        return Activator.Create<T>();
    }

    public TDerived CreateDerived<TDerived>() where TDerived : T
    {
        return Activator.Create<TDerived>();
    }
}
```

and in this setup you can:

```
class IMyInterf {}
class MyType : IMyInterf {}
class MyChildType : MyType {}

MyType tmp1 = FooProvider.Get<MyType>().CreateDirect();

MyChildType tmp1 = FooProvider.Get<MyType>().CreateDerived<MyChildType>();

MyChildType tmp1 = FooProvider.Get<IMyInterf>().CreateDerived<MyChildType>();
```

This is only sketch, written by hand without compiling, but it shows the general idea.

If you remove "CreateDirect" and rename "CreateDerived" to just Create, you'd get something similar to your code, but simplier. And of course, you may now mix and squash those two separate classes into one if you really need, but I see no real point in it :)

EDIT:

And of course instead of `Provider<T>` you can introduce a `ProviderBase<T>` and multiple `OrangeProvider:ProviderBase<Orange>` just for the sake of easier building/finding the proper provider, but still the actual `Get<>` will have to return the actual `ProviderBase<T>` or `IProvider<T>`.

Comment: The idea behind my design is that I want to return the provider for a given model, *and* I'd like to be able to substitute this provider when testing (with a Mock provider). Your suggestion does not allow this. Plus, one provider can serve different (known) related model types.

Comment: I already told you this is a sketch/overview. The last two lines show that one provider typef by "X" can construct "Y" or "Z", so the one-for-many-types is fulfilled. Mocking/substituting the providers for testing is trivial: instead of returning `Provider<T>` from the `Get<T>` - return `IProvider<T>` - and now your static FooProvider can return a mock while in test environment..

Comment: I mean, even with support for mocking, there's still no need to mix the factory/provider/model classes.

Comment: I'm from a Java background, and what I'm trying to do is fairly easy as the generics don't behave the same. So, what you're saying is thst I *need* to have a provider for *every* model types?

Comment: I've just posted second example. Please give it a look.